# extundelete does not finish its work

Tags: debian, data-recovery, ext4

I need to restore a file on sda7 so I remounted ro und startet extundelete

```
manuel@P5KC:~/recovery/RECOVERED_FILES$ sudo extundelete --restore-all /dev/sda7
WARNING: Extended attributes are not restored.
Loading filesystem metadata ... 688 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 18110 descriptors loaded.
Writing output to directory RECOVERED_FILES/
Searching for recoverable inodes in directory / ... 
1554 recoverable inodes found.
Looking through the directory structure for deleted files ... 
Unable to restore inode 2228446 (lost+found/latex): No data found.
```

But the directory `RECOVERED_FILES` is empty. Am I doing something wrong or is my data lost? Filesystem is ext4. At the end, logged in as su, I am even getting a segmentation fault.

---

Debian Wheezy 3.2.0-4-amd64

Answer (score 1):

Your extundelete is possibly too old. I had the same issue, after updating extundelete it recovered just the same file where it stated "no data found" before.

Answer (score 0):

When a file is deleted, the space it used to occupy is free for grabs for the next use. If so, the previous file contents can't be recovered. Sure, there are programs that rummage around trying to find files that haven't been reclaimed yet. But *any* activity at all after the deletion can reuse the file's space, and Linux systems are quite active all the time.

First thing to learn about Unix: If you call for an action, it is done. No second-guessing, no asking for confirmation (you are the boss, remember?). And most of the time no way to undo. Don't *ever* get into the mind-set that file deletes can be undone. They can (sometimes), but Murphy's law decrees that only if the file wasn't important in the first place.